# Excel to count to the next cell

Tags: excel

I want to format a column with a formula that types next to a cell's content in parenthesis the count of cells to the next cell down which has text.

like this:

```
[word1 (3)][        ][        ]
[         ][        ][        ]
[         ][        ][        ]
[word2 (1)][        ][        ]
[word3 (6)][        ][        ]
[         ][        ][        ]
[         ][        ][        ]
[         ][        ][        ]
[         ][        ][        ]
[         ][        ][        ]
[word4    ][        ][        ]
[         ][        ][        ]
[         ][        ][        ]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that last value be (6) rather than (7), to be consistent with the first two? And will these values be added to the first column (concatenated), or appear in the adjacent column? If you want them in the same cell then this wouldn't be a formula, it would require code.

Comment: You're right a typo there (edited to 6) - I want this formula to affect only the A column. and only display the count to the next cell down. If there is no cell with text down, the cell displays only the word and not the "(00)" next to it. So, if possible have all in the same cell. Thanks for helping guys!

Comment: Formulas are cool. If below works that is great. Else can ask help with a macro to the same

Comment: Formulas work if I use 2 columns. I want the formula to work in one column (the first one: A). Let's say Excel has only one column. What would you do to that column to act as the post question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have headers and your phrases are in column A and you want the word and space counts in column B so that your data setup looks like this:

[image: tigeravatar word and space count formula]

The formula in cell B2 and copied down is:

```
=IF(A2="","","word"&COUNTA(B$1:B1)-COUNTBLANK(B$1:B1)&IFERROR(" ("&MATCH("*",$A3:$A$100,0)&")",""))
```

[EDIT]:
You have informed me that the data setup has no headers.
In that case, use this formula in cell B1:

```
=IF(A1="","","word1"&IFERROR(" ("&MATCH("*",$A2:$A$100,0)&")",""))
```

And then in cell B2 and copied down:

```
=IF(A2="","","word"&COUNTA(B$1:B1)-COUNTBLANK(B$1:B1)+1&IFERROR(" ("&MATCH("*",$A3:$A$100,0)&")",""))
```

If you want it to look at more than just the first 100 cells in column A, change the `$A$100` to be `$A$1000` or `$A$10000` or `$A$65000`.  Basically just extend the range as far as you deem necessary.  Make sure to change that in both formulas.

Comment: There's no header. I can type anywhere on that column. Can I have all the column formatted so that if the cell I'm writing on, "sees" another one with text below it, it counts the empty cells (including 'itself') and adds that sum next to its content in this format: "word (00)"

Comment: Is it possible to have all the formulas in one column? I have only the first column free. Plus when I typed "word (00)" I meant that it could be any word. Not exactly "word". Thanks very much for helping tiger!

Comment: If you need to have the results be in the same cells as the original data, that will require a macro unfortunately.